# Grails 2.0 Redirect Include App Context Even Though I Have It Set To "/"

Tags: grails, redirect

Using Grails 2.0.1 (upgraded from 1.3.7). In application.properties I have app.context = "/" and all is generally working well.  However, my redirects now attempt to include an app context.

redirect action: "edit", id:genAttribute.id

So instead of

http://localhost:8080/genAttribute/edit/55

I end up with

http://localhost:8080/bh/genAttribute/edit/55

which of course doesn't work.  Another interesting piece of this is that the g:link tag works fine.  It just seems to be the redirect calls from my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled across [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7571) so the solution is to remove the grails.serverURL from Config.groovy.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was looking at this problem for hours after upgrading to grails 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an invalid grails.serverURL config property, it's explained [here](http://pledbrook.github.com/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html) in the "Redirects" section, quoting:

> As a side-effect, the redirect() is now dependent on the
>   grails.serverURL configuration setting. **If this doesn't match the URL
>   of your application, redirects will stop working**.
>
> The simplest way to avoid this problem is to remove the setting unless
>   you need it. If you need it (usually for production deployments) then
>   the value should already match the URL of your application. This
>   mostly impacts development where old projects often have a legacy
>   value that doesn't work.